# SessionStorage duplicates object with the same ID

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I am currently making a simple cart with vue.js + sessionStorage. Here's my js code(vue.js method):

```
storeLocalStorage(){
    var tempitem = store.getters.printCart;

    if(tempitem.length){
      if(sessionStorage.length){
        var existingCart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.cart);
        var size = Object.keys(existingCart).length;
        //console.log(existingCart);

        const index = existingCart.findIndex(existingCart => existingCart.itemID === tempitem.itemID);
        //console.log(index);

        if (index === -1) {
          existingCart.push(tempitem[0]);
        } else {
          existingCart[index].itemQuantity = existingCart[index].itemQuantity + tempitem.itemQuantity;
        }
        
        let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(existingCart);
        sessionStorage.setItem('cart', myObj_serialized); 
      } 
      else {
        let myObj_serialized = JSON.stringify(tempitem);
        sessionStorage.setItem('cart', myObj_serialized);
      }
    }
  }
```

And here's my Object Arrays:

TempItem:

```
    {
    itemID: "a1b1c1",
    itemName: "sessionItem1",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1,
  },
  {
    itemID: "a2b2c2",
    itemName: "sessionItem2",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1,
  }
```

sessionStorage items:

```
  0:
    itemID: "a1b1c1",
    itemName: "sessionItem1",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1,
  1:
    itemID: "a3b3c3",
    itemName: "sessionItem3",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1,
  2:
    itemID: "a2b2c2",
    itemName: "sessionItem2",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1,
```

What I want to accomplish is whenever a tempitem object has the same ID with a sessionStorage item, their quantity would be summed up and passed to the sessionStorage Item, but if it doesn't, it will add another index in the sessionStorage. But what happens is, instead of adding both the quantities, it creates another index with the same item but different quantities.

```
0:
    itemID: "a1b1c1",
    itemName: "sessionItem1",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1,
  1:
    itemID: "a1b1c1",
    itemName: "sessionItem1",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 5,
```

How do i accomplish this?

Comment: did the solution not work for you as provided in the another question ? Do you want to sum up the quantities or override the quantities?

Comment: It did answer my question before and it was working earlier, but it doesn't work if my tempitem has two or more objects inside so i tried the other solution posted there

Comment: If `tempitem` is an *array* of items, you'll have to perform a separate lookup for each item in the array.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I want to sum up the quantities

Comment: Since the ID is supposed to be unique anyway, you could just use an object with the ID as key instead of an array.

Comment: @Ryan , it just answered the question.

Comment: I believe your `sessionStorage` object merely needs `itemID` and `itemQuantity`. Storing the other properties is kind of redundant since those can be looked up in the original. This might come in handy thinking about storage limitations and planning ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use this logic to sum the quantities , rest all remains same.
> Loop over the new array items, check for the object in existing array
> , if it exists add the quantity else add the new object in the
> existing array.

```js
var arr = [{
    itemID: "a1b1c1",
    itemName: "sessionItem1",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1,
},{
    itemID: "a3b3c3",
    itemName: "sessionItem3",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1},
           {
    itemID: "a2b2c2",
    itemName: "sessionItem2",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1}];

// new items array
var newArr= [{
    itemID: "a1b1c1",
    itemName: "sessionItem1",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 1},
             {
    itemID: "a1b1c1",
    itemName: "sessionItem1",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 5},
{
    itemID: "a5b5c5",
    itemName: "sessionItem1",
    itemPrice: 550,
    itemQuantity: 5}]


newArr.forEach(newEle => {
    let obj = arr.find(ob => ob.itemID === newEle.itemID);
  if(obj!==undefined){
     obj.itemQuantity+=newEle.itemQuantity;
  } else{
    arr.push(newEle);
    }

})

    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You can skip `obj!==null` in this case.

Comment: This solved it for me! Thanks @HarmandeepSinghKalsi! I just placed the sessionStorage.setItem inside the conditions and now its working fine.

Comment: Good to hear Ryan . Happy Learning!